# При переходе из поисковика Яндекса появляется ysclid в ссылке

Tags: url, яндекс-поиск

При переходе из поисковика Яндекса появляется дополнительная utm метка (если она так называется) в адресной строке. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-то обрабатывать такие ссылки чтобы эта метка не передавалась?
[image: пример]